# Scala.jdk.CollectionConverter

Tags: java, scala

In my application I was using the method `asScala` from `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` but when running I had a warning that this method was deprecated since 2.13.0 `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` instead.

But when I try to use it on my Java List I keep having this error :

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[play.data.validation.ValidationError]
 required: ?{def asScala: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method asScalaBufferConverter in object JavaConverters of type [A](l: java.util.List[A])collection.JavaConverters.AsScala[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[A]]
 and method ListHasAsScala in trait AsScalaExtensions of type [A](l: java.util.List[A])jdk.CollectionConverters.ListHasAsScala[A]
 are possible conversion functions from java.util.List[play.data.validation.ValidationError] to ?{def asScala: ?}
```

Even if I'm not importing `scala.collection.JavaConverters._`.

I'm coding with the play framework 2.7.3, my view (twirl template) has a parameter `form: Form[InformationData]` and the error occurs on this

```
@if(form.hasGlobalErrors) {
        @form.globalErrors.asScala.map { error: play.data.validation.ValidationError =>
            <div>
                @error.key: @error.message
            </div>
        }
    }
```

How can I manage this ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution : since I'm doing this on java code I need to use `scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConverters._` to make it work on a `Java.util.List`